# Selecting Methods in Parent View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Let's say I have a custom `UIView` with a `UIButton`. Can this button's target reference a selector in the parent view of the custom `UIView`? Or even be passed a selector from the implementing view? I have tried the following with no luck:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    var button = UIButton()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let buttonSize = min(frame.height, frame.width)/2.0
        self.button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonSize, buttonSize))
        self.button.setTitle("Example Title", forState: .Normal)
        self.button.center = self.center
        self.addSubview(button)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addTargetToButton(selector: Selector) {
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

}
```

I was hoping to use something like this to create a menu with an undefined number of buttons that could all be given targets in an implementing `UIViewController`. Here would be the basic syntax of the VC:

```
private extension Selector {
    static let actionIWantTapped = #selector(CustomViewController.actionIWant(_:))
}

class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
    var customView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        customView.addTargetToButton(.actionIWantTapped)

    }

    func actionIWant(sender: UIButton!) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want the selector to be from Parent class, it can be done

Comment: Would there be something wrong with passing a selector like #selector(MyViewController.actionIWant(_:))? I'm getting an error there (unrecognized selector). I'll update the question to make it more clear what syntax I'm using in the parent

Comment: Normally you can simply pass a function as a parameter in swift, but in case  of UIButton selector in swift, you can't use the parameter in the function which is a function in swift.